# What is Ultra Strike and how can we get it?

Tags: ingress

I heard there is a new weapon called Ultra Strike which is supposedly [exclusive to Motorola](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/jKDDcW6HMmb) phones, which will come with Ingress pre-installed.

- How does the weapon work, in comparison to existing ones (XMP, virii)?
- Is it only exclusive to the hardware with pre-installed Ingress, or all Motorola devices?
- Are there ways for other devices to activate hacking it from portals (app to spoof phone type to Ingress? custom Ingress apk? )

Comment: Where did you hear/read that? I seriously doubt that this is true. Your items are stored on the Ingress game server, and the client does not send that kind of details about your phone to the server.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Was announced today in one of the Ingress Report videos. I wouldn't blame you for not knowing, anything relating to the story/lore is easily the worst part of that game.  Reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIVzLHE6Fnk&feature=share&list=PLDEUWItbkQ58tbLEFP6lA1PtnPk48jDBr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

### Ultrastrikes are now hackable by all!

#### What it is then?

It's a burster, you fire it just like **XMP**. It's a bit different though,..

- Radius **10 - 30 m**
- **MUCH** higher damage
- **Very steep damage falloff** (you **must** stand right on a resonator)

Moreover, it has a new **tactical** functionality:
If you stand right on the center of a portal, you can destroy its shields and other mods!

Answer (score 5):

If you rewatch the video you posted and read the thread with it you get the official answer that states:

- Only a new, yet to be released, Motorola phone can obtain the Ultra Strike weapon via hacking portals.
- The weapon can be shared like other items and any phone can use the weapon.

Answer (score 1):

I met an L8 with ultra strikes. He said they are very powerful at extremely short range. He said you have to be standing on top of a resonator for it to be effective: if you are even a few meters away from the resonator, it won't do anything. He said even normal GPS wiggle can make him "miss".

Answer (score 0):

it comes with the droid maxx and i assume the ultra and the other one.  I got it today it also came with 50 burst and res plus power cubes at your current level.  I accidentally fired one off but not sure what it did if it did anything.